# Gradle unknown command-line option '-X'

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm getting this error-dialog and have no idea where it's coming from. 
Dialog:

[image: error-dialog]

Command-line options are empty:

[image: gradle settings]

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Right click on your Package name in the Project window and select "Open Module Settings" -> then select compiler from the left panel. See if there are any command line options..

Comment: Thanks @sampath , but your suggestion didn't lead to a solution. I started a new project a couple of times and eventually it stopped giving me the error.