# Run application via gradlew with -Xmx and -Xms

Tags: gradle, memory-management, jvm, gradlew

I have an application. I run it via

```
gradlew run-app
```

Or debug

```
gradlew debug-app
```

It works. How do I pass '-Xmx' argument into the application which I run (debug)?
Is it possible to do so without edditing `build.gradle` file?

I found this
[Gradle unknown command-line option '-X'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172021/gradle-unknown-command-line-option-x)

I get a similar error when I try

```
gradlew debug-app -Xmx2000m
```

Error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Problem configuring task :debug-app from command line.
> Unknown command-line option '-X'.
```

---

I tried to create a file `gradle.properties` in `GRADLE_USER_HOME` directory (by default, it is USER_HOME/.gradle).

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=4256m -Xmx4256m -Xms2000m
```

I also tried to `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2000m` in project folder `gradle.properties`.

And even then when I run an application, I see Commited Memory size is < 520 MiB

[image]

And this is when I run it as a normal Java App

[image]

In the second case, when I run the application as a normal Java app with -Xms, -Xmx, Commited Memory size is about 3.5 GiB because I passed `-Xmx4512m -Xms2512m` parameters.

Comment: I edited my answer

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Add this in your `gradle.properties` file :

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2000m
```

From [here](https://docs.gradle.org/4.0/userguide/build_environment.html)

> **org.gradle.jvmargs**
>
> Specifies the jvmargs used for the daemon process. The setting is
>   particularly useful for tweaking memory settings. At the moment the
>   default settings are pretty generous with regards to memory.

edit : my answer what about the gradle daemon jvm, not the app jvm. You have to use the [jvmArgs property](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec:jvmArgs)

> The extra arguments to use to launch the JVM for the process. Does not
>   include system properties and the minimum/maximum heap size.

Comment: What does `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Xss1M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` mean in the `gradle.properties`

Comment: It sets specific jvmargs for the daemon process

Comment: also note that if you're using 32bit jdk you can only set the heap space to max 4g (on windows 2g). In my case gradle couldn't startet a new gradle daemon because I was using 32bit jdk and I set the heap space too large.

Comment: Or on command line:  `./gradlew -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g ...`

Answer (score 22):

Firstly, thanks @ToYonos for leading me to the right direction.

Secondly, I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9648945/4587961.
I ran my app from command line.

```
set GRADLE_OPTS=-Xms1724m -Xmx5048m
gradlew debug-app
```

Note, CMD Windows command SET works locally, so if you close your terminal, `GRADLE_OPTS` will not be set. For Linux, you can use

```
export GRADLE_OPTS=WHATEVER
```

This is what I wanted to achieve.

[image]

Comment: One liner (Linux, at least): `GRADLE_OPTS="-Xms1724m -Xmx5048m" ./gradlew debug-app`

Comment: GRADLE_OPTS="-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs='-Xms4g'" it should be like this actually

Answer (score 21):

Using **application** plugin one can use **applicationDefaultJvmArgs** property

```
apply plugin: 'application'    
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Xms1024m", "-Xmx2048m"]
```

The arguments will be applied to **run** task and to start script of your application

[more info](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html)

Comment: Thanks, it is also nice. However, one drawback. What if in debug I want to run with command line arguments, and in deployment mode I don't need command line arguments. I prefer not putting extra lines of code into production / deploy mode.

Comment: You can use ${System.env.VAR_NAME} by configuating of applicationDefaultJvmArgs. Due the limitation of plugin the variables have to be converted before run. See this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/29464373/1076187.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately gradle [doensn't honor](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/21505) `applicationDefaultJvmArgs` in 7.x branch.

As a workaround you can use following code (gradle.kts version, groovy version pretty similar):

```
tasks.withType<JavaExec>().configureEach {
  jvmArgs = listOf("-Xms1g", "-Xmx2g")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case Invalidate cache and restart the android studio(which is automatically restarted) then the error will be gone after restarting the android studio

[image]

then
[image]