# How can I collect a heap dump from Gradle tests in a Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, heap-dump

I trying to diagnose a memory leak while running my integration tests in my Spring Boot App.

When I am running :

```
./gradlew test -i --XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/Users/ng.newbie/Desktop/heapdump.bin
```

I keep getting OOM errors:

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pem.item.service.exchange.allocation-97"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pem.item.service.exchange.itemAssortment-97"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pem.item.service.exchange.order-97"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pem.item.service.exchange.planning-97"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "HikariPool-37 housekeeper"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "HikariPool-1 housekeeper"
```

But no heap dump in the specified directory.

I have also tried adding the following to my `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:PermSize=128m -Xmx1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/Users/ng.newbie/Desktop/crash.hprof
```

No change.

What am I doing wrong ?

How can I collect the heap dumps of the `gradle test` ?

Comment: I don't think you can simply pass jvm args like this to gradle. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701947/run-application-via-gradlew-with-xmx-and-xms

Comment: The linked article states: `my answer what about the gradle daemon jvm, not the app jvm. You have to use the jvmArgs property`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following in the `build.gradle` file

```
test {
    jvmArgs '-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'
}
```

Comment: Where will the heap dump be generated ?

Comment: In the current directory